# insert into table 1 update table 2 column x from table 1 column y

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and Sql Server
Trying to insert into table 1 second step to update table 2 column x from table 1 column y.
The problem while updating its update the whole column x

My tables : 
table Car
(CarId
CarModel
Color
LicensePlate
CarOdometer)

table JobInfo
(JobId
JobNum
Date
StartLocation
Destination
StartOdometer
EndOdometer
Parking
CarId
UserId)

UPDATE  Car  SET CarOdometer  = (SELECT TOP 1 EndOdometer FROM JobInfo WHERE CarId = Car.CarId ORDER BY EndOdometer DESC)

Update Car set Car.CarOdometer = JobInfo.EndOdometer from JobInfo where  JobInfo.carId=( SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(JobInfo.CarId));

was trying to use inner join but dosn't work

```
            string query1 = "INSERT INTO JobInfo (JobNum,Date,StartLocation,Destination,EndOdometer,Parking,CarId,StartOdometer)" +
                                                  "VALUES(@JobNum,@Date,@StartLocation,@Destination,@EndOdometer,@Parking,@CarId,@StartOdometer)";


            string query2 = "Update Car SET Car.CarOdometer = (Select top 1 JobInfo.EndOdometer FROM JobInfo INNER JOIN Car ON JobInfo.CarId = Car.CarId "+
                             "ORDER BY JobInfo.EndOdometer desc) WHERE Car.CarId = Car.CarId";
            sqlCon.Open();
            var sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, sqlCon);
            var sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, sqlCon);

            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNum", jobModel.JobNum);
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", jobModel.Date.ToString());
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartLocation", jobModel.StartLocation);
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", jobModel.Destination);
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndOdometer", jobModel.EndOdometer);
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parking", Convert.ToDecimal(jobModel.Parking));
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarId", Convert.ToInt32(jobModel.CarId));
            sqlCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartOdometer", Convert.ToInt32(jobModel.StartOdometer));
            //Updating CarOdometer from EndOdometer
            sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarOdometer", Convert.ToInt32(jobModel.CarOdometer));


            sqlCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

after update  only CarOdometer in CarId=1 or depend on CarId will be ussed  should change and not all the records

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to change all the records but those which are included in JobInfo table, you can check it:

```
UPDATE Car SET CarOdometer = (SELECT TOP 1 EndOdometer FROM JobInfo 
               WHERE CarId = Car.CarId ORDER BY EndOdometer DESC) 
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 EndOdometer FROM JobInfo 
                    WHERE CarId = Car.CarId ORDER BY EndOdometer DESC)
```